# How to open android bundle file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bundle

How can I unpack/pack .bundle files from the installed games/application in android?

I have unpacked an apk and there are .bundle file types in its asset. I would like to unpack the .bundle files and see what is inside.

I tried google and did not find any way to unpack the bundle files from the installed games/application in android.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking debug help should provide a minimal reproducible example. please elaborate and post an example for your code

Comment: Did you find out?